# Mysql database table id reuse

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, auto-increment

In one of my projects, the current implementation of a log system uses a mysql table. The applications released to customers write some log information to the table on a daily basis. There is a script on our server to automatically remove all logs that are more than 60 days old. The problem is that the primary id keeps growing and some time in the future, it will outgrow the limit. The id currently is set to int auto_increment. So what's the best solution for this problem. I am no expert in database and your help is highly appreciated. I tried to search on Stack Overflow but could not find answer for my case.

Should I change int to bigint? How do I do that without interrupting the db's normal operation? I want to avoid any down time. But even with bigint, the id will reach the limit one day. It looks like I am just delaying the problem. Is there a good solution? Can  I configure the db so it can re-use ids that become available after the script removes old data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to delete the table, but archive the content after 60 days i.e. delete from the main table and insert into the archived table. For the second issue, if the value of the PK is increasing like hell try the type 'bigint'

Comment: Thanks, Sashi for the quick reply. The old data in our case is really no use. So we simply delete them. But I agree with you that in general it is a good idea to archive them instead. How can I change it to bigint safely without interrupting my service? Also as I mentioned in my post, is there a better solution because even with bigint, it is not really solving the problem but just delaying the inevitable. Thanks!

Comment: alter table table_name modify column_name bigint

Comment: Thanks, Sashi! I have upped 1 for your comment. Will wait a bit to see if others have better solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think 4294967295 (for unsigned int) rows of log data is enough for this matter, unless your application is still in a premature deployment phase where logs of application actions have to be generated. Otherwise, try to improve your utility script so it can rebuild the table(s) and restart the index. Of course, it will spend a few seconds more, but I think it worth enough. Anyway, the best (ideal) database-driven application produces smaller data (incl. logs) but still provides a complete-set of data in a good integrity.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. The logs are not for debugging purpose. They are real data that customers need. they can be viewed online by the customers. And because it is machine generated records, it can increase pretty quickly. So 4B is definitely not enough for a long run. Could you please let me know how I can rebuild the table and restart the index safely without loosing the existing data and with minimal downtime? Thanks!